# Getting Coldfusion Complex Objects error but don't have a complex object

Tags: coldfusion

I'm getting "Complex object types cannot be converted to simple values. " locationId and/or operatorId is sent via url and is always a simple number ('304'). Here's the code for the query:

```
select  *
from  table1, table2
where table1.u_construct_id(+)=table2.u_construct_id  
and table1.LOCATION_ID  = #locationId#
and   table1.OPERATOR_ID = #operatorId#
```

Comment: Did you dump the values to see what values they contain? `<cfdump var="#URL#">` Also, the code does not scope the variables which raises the possibility (small) that you are actually getting the wrong variable ie same name different scope. (As always, the real query should be using cfqueryparam on all parameters.)

Comment: Which variable is erroring? Also please scope the variables as Leigh said.

Comment: As per what others have said: post the full actual error message.  If you have robust exception handling switched on, it'll tell you the exact line that is erroring, which - as you suggest - probably isn't the bit of code you've quoted above.  Also do some of your own troubleshooting... dump out the variables in the vicinity of the code that erroring and verify they contain what you think they contain.

Comment: The "Complex object types cannot be converted to simple values" error often indicates that you omitted the parenthesis in a function call. Like var itemId = getItem; instead of  var itemId = getItem();. As others said, try to get the line number where the error is thrown, look into logfiles, turn on debugging, switch on robust exception handling, dump vars.

Comment: You should also scope those variable references. If you're just using locationId, you can't guarantee that it's picking that up from the URL. If you have a local variable by the same name, you'll be picking that up instead. Make sure you cfqueryparam your values, and make sure that you explicitly declare the scope you want the variable to come from.

Answer (score 8):

What are the ***full*** error details? Does it specifically point to the query, or simply to one of the lines near the query, which is causing you to make the assumption the query is at fault.

(There is nothing in what you've posted so far that says that this is a query problem.)

In any case, your query is currently liable to SQL injection, and should be changed to this:

```
select  *
from  table1, table2
where table1.u_construct_id (+)= table2.u_construct_id  
and table1.LOCATION_ID = <cfqueryparam value="#url.locationId#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" />
and table1.OPERATOR_ID = <cfqueryparam value="#url.operatorId#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" />
```

Note that as well as cfqueryparam (which should generally be used on all dynamic variables, but especially client-supplied ones), the two variables have been `url` scoped, and it may well be that scoping the variables correctly is the fix (if locationId or operatorId exist in other scopes, as non-simple variables).

Answer (score -3):

Thanks for all the help, but the answer turned out to be that operatorId had to be renamed. Not sure why that worked, but suspect that CF is seeing that as a reserved term.

Comment: It sounds highly likely that you have another variable with the same name `operatorId` which was overwriting this one - the solution is _NOT_ to rename the variable, the solution is to correctly scope variables (as pointed out several times).

Comment: ok, can you point me to a simple tutorial that explains scoping variables? I thought I was elsewhere in the code; not shown. but maybe I don't understand scoping as well as I should.

Comment: The docs are always a good place to start: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7fd5.html